# Use module as singleton

Tags: javascript, node.js

In javascript we can use module as singleton.

```
//a.js
export default {str:'aaa'}

//b.js
import singleton from 'a.js'
singleton.str='bbb'

//c.js
import singleton from 'a.js'
singleton.str='ccc'
```

I want to use it to be the configure of my module. Is there any risk? It will always be a singleton in every module system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I want to use it to be the configure of my module. Is there any risk? It will always be a singleton in every module system?

Yes, an ESM module (and a commonjs module) is guaranteed to return the same instance. **

While this is bad design (because it's mutable global state anyone can import and change and it's hard to keep track of) - it's entirely guaranteed to always work.

If you're interested in the details of how Node.js loads modules - you can see the reference of the [resolver algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolver_algorithm_specification) in our docs and the [relevant bits for CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) here.

---

This is safe to rely on. I'll try to explain *why*. Imagine modules *didn't* work this way:

```js
//a.js
export default class Foo { /* some code */ }

//b.js
import Foo from './a';
```

If whenever `b` and other files import the class `Foo` they might get a different instance - stuff like `instanceof` wouldn't work across modules and it would be impossible to rely on references.

This is *generally* why this is both guaranteed and supported.

As a fun side node - [ES Modules are live references](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_imports-as-views-on-exports) :]

<sub>**the caveat is that it's possible to "opt out" - for example by deleting the module from `require.cache` and setting `require.parent` in commonjs. However, this is never the default behavior.</sub>

Comment: useful answer, however, is there any source to back it up?

Comment: @Pac0 I added a source though to be honest - I don't know it from reading it - I mostly know this from working on modules in Node.js core - it's something that in practice applications rely on quite often. I'll add more info

Comment: certainly, but some doc links never hurts. The link to nodeja doc states it very clearly, even for me who is completely rusty with this tech. thanks , great answer now.

Comment: @Pac0 by all means - asking for citations and references in answers is typically a good idea and answers are expected to back things that are not easily provable (like if something is guaranteed by the spec of platform) up. You were right to ask for citations backing up the answer here (and I appreciate it).